# selectbox and checkbox not working in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-multiselect

```
<select id="multi-select-demo" multiple="multiple"> 
</select>
```

in below code we want to assign dynamic options values through ajax but it's not working

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'get_checkparishdata',
  data: { "campids": optionValue },
  success: function (data2) {
    new_data2 = data2;
    if (new_data2 == '<option>No Record Found</option>') {
      $(".bootparish").html(new_data2);
      $("#multi-select-demo").html(new_data2);
      $('#multi-select-demo').multiselect();
    } else {
      $(".bootparish").html(new_data2);
      $("#multi-select-demo").html(new_data2);
    }
  }
});
```

//want to assign dynamic option value

```
$option_parish = '';
foreach($datapar as $Jurisdiction_parish)
{               
$option_parish.='<option value="'.$Jurisdiction_parish.'" 
selected>'.$Jurisdiction_parish.'</option>';
}   
return $option_parish;
```

Comment: Where do you set `optionValue`?

Comment: please add your server side code also add data that get in data2

Comment: Not sure why you feel the need to `new_data2 = data2;` all that achieves is wasting memory

Comment: $option_parish = '';
foreach($datapar as $Jurisdiction_parish)
{               
$option_parish.='<option value="'.$Jurisdiction_parish.'" 
selected>'.$Jurisdiction_parish.'</option>';
}   
return $option_parish; @kerbholz

Comment: @priya, what are you getting data2

Comment: <option value="52" selected="">52</option><option value="53" selected="">53</option>

Comment: i am getting option tag with dynamic values